# How to test SAPUI5 apps locally in apache tomacat installed in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, testing, sapui5, web.xml

I am working on SAPUI5 app which was created long back and running successfully. Now I need to do some enhancements and for that I downloaded the app and uploaded in eclipse.

Now when I am running this app locally - It is not working as the XMLHTTP Request says 404 (Not Found) when accessing the backend OData service.

```
URI is : /sap/opu/odata/sap/Z****SRV";
```

I understand that I need to add `http://<host>:<port>` before URI.

But I cannot change it in all the places. I found out that we can write `<param-value>` in web.xml file but I did and still it is not working

Can someone guide me how?

Comment: For which requests does it return 404? Is it the bootstrapper call? Simply change to the CDN URL, or have a local version of UI5 in your web server available

Comment: Agree with @qualiture. This question contains so little information about what exactly goes wrong that it's not possible to formulate an answer. Actually deserves a down-vote...

Comment: Sorry for that. Edited the question for better understanding of the issue.

Comment: Your application expects to be running on an ABAP back-end, not on your PC. On you ABAP back-end the URI `/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z****SRV` will be available, without prefixing `http://<host>:<port>` as these will default to the server the app is running on. Hope this helps to get your application running.

Comment: I understand that I can test this app in ABAP Gateway. But I need to test this application in eclipse using tomcat. The requirement I have is similar to "How to test Fiori app in tomcat"?